# Python File handling: Seaching for specific numbers

Tags: python

I'm creating a document in which I need to record license plates of vehicles (it's a practice exercise, nothing illegal) and calculate the speed they travel at and display all the vehicles that are travelling over 60 miles per hour. I'm pretty new to file handling and have no idea how to get Python to search for specific numbers. Help!

Code so far:

```
plate = "blank"
sensor1 = "blank"
sensor2 = "blank"
timetaken = "blank"
speed = "blank"

plate = input("Please input the license plate of the vehicle.")

sensor1 = float(input("Input the time the vehicle passed sensor 1."))
sensor2 = float(input("Input the time the vehicle passed sensor 2."))

timetaken = (sensor2 - sensor1)

print("The time taken for the vehicle to travel between the two sensors in  seconds:")
print(timetaken)

speed = (5/timetaken)
print("Vehicle speed in miles per hour:")
print(speed)
```

Edit: I appreciate the help but I'm not sure how I can search the .txt document that will be created later on to search for a specific license plate.

Comment: Don't inlude code as a link to an image. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28807604/edit) and include your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (speed>60)
    #Do what you want to
```

Answer (score 0):

In this part you store speed in your variable and then in second line you overwrite it with string.

```
speed = (5/timetaken)
speed = ("Vehicle speed in miles per hour:")
print(speed)
```

As [Mohit Bhasi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28807708/2229132) mentioned checking the speed is not that difficult, just make sure you know what units you are working with, either meters per second or kilometers per second.

Reading/writing file is fairly simple in Python and [documentation offers few examples how to do it](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). [Or check out some other sources as well](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm).

Regarding your task, I would do something like this:

1. Open file
2. Read each line with data
3. Get the plates string, and speed value which you should parse to number
4. Check for speed limit
5. Print out
6. Close file

PS: No one is going to write it for you. That would take all fun out of it. :-)

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that mistake. =D