# Python File handling. Detecting license plates that don't match the british system

Tags: python, regex, file-handling

I've been tasked with creating a Python program that will identify license plates that don't match the British registry system.

In the UK most vehicle registrations are in the format:

> • Two letters
>
> • Two numbers
>
> • Three letters.

For example, AZ01 XYZ

The plates that do not match this system will be written to a `.txt` document and have their average speed record alongside too.

I'm new to `Python` and have little to no experience coding and have nothing to show thus far.

Comment: Is this for a class? Hopefully you would have gotten at least some pointers to things to try if that's the case. If it's for work, I'm not really sure it's fair to expect others to do your work for you.

Comment: You will probably need to spend a week with the basics: For example: http://www.diveintopython3.net/ - Once you have some code, you can come back and edit your question.

Comment: We're not here to help you cheat on your GCSE coursework. Do your own research, and make an attempt to implement this yourself.

Comment: It also looks like you are trying to find someone to write the code for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807604/python-file-handling-seaching-for-specific-numbers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First check if each set of chars isalpha (letter) or digit (number), 
if not a valid plate append it to file.

licence_plate = 'AZ01 XYZ'

```
if not (licence_plate[:2].isalpha() 
        and licence_plate[2:4].isdigit() 
        and licence_plate[5:].isalpha()):
            fo = open("ishouldstudymore.txt", "aw")
            fo.write(licence_plate)
            fo.close()
```

It's imperative that you read the following links in order to understand what's above.

[isDigit](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm)

[isAlpha](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isalpha.htm)

[Python Strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

[Python File IO](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)

[Python Loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm)

Comment: The core is there, if you want to learn it. More important than the core it's the links

Comment: Thanks! I'd certainly study more I'm just short of time at present.